# After the installation of SSL on my Django application, i encounter a 403 Forbidden error preventing access to CSS files. The domain is memcur.com

Tags: django, nginx, django-models, django-views, django-forms

After the installation of SSL on my Django application, i encounter a 403 Forbidden error preventing access to CSS files. I am using nginx and ubunto. The /var/log/nginx/error.log shows the following continuously, though i have applied:
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /root/memcur/static/
sudo chmod -R 755 /root/memcur/static/

/var/log/nginx/error.log:
"/root/memcur/static/libs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 103.180.203.6, server: memcur.com, request: "GET /static/libs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js HTTP/1.1", host: "memcur.com", referrer: "https://memcur.com/account/login/?next=/"

"/root/memcur/static/libs/metismenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 103.180.203.6, server: memcur.com, request: "GET /static/libs/metismenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js HTTP/1.1", host: "memcur.com", referrer: "https://memcur.com/account/login/?next=/"

"/root/memcur/static/libs/node-waves/dist/waves.min.js" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 103.180.203.6, server: memcur.com, request: "GET /static/libs/node-waves/dist/waves.min.js HTTP/1.1", host: "memcur.com", referrer: "https://memcur.com/account/login/?next=/"

"/root/memcur/static/js/app.js" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 103.180.203.6, server: memcur.com, request: "GET /static/js/app.js HTTP/1.1", host: "memcur.com", referrer: "https://memcur.com/account/login/?next=/"

The domain is memcur.com.

The css, js, and images are not loading. Pleas visit and give me a suggestion to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

add the www-data user to the group that your project user is in.

```
sudo usermod -a -G your_user www-data
```

Then restart nginx.

Comment: Still the 403 is encountered, when i try  to access the site.